# Pivot Table - Calculated item - custom calculations

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have used a calculated item to calculate the ***year on year growth*** and also ***CAGR growth*** in the pivot.  But when it comes to the Total,  it is taking sum by default instead of Year on Year growth & CAGR growth.

***Year on Year Growth*** from Column M to Column V
   ***CAGR Growth*** from Column W to Y

Can someone please help me?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro and doing the modifications by hand? PivotTables are a pain (for me) to write macros for, and using Excel's recording tool while I format it to what I like helps me immensly

Comment: You can't change  the Total formula manually for pivot calculated item. So there is no use of recording a macro

Comment: I am using Office 365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a way to solve this problem.

As you all aware, it is not possible to get the %s in the calculated item and it always gives the sum by default.

I) I have added one more pivot and in that I have changed the turnover rows to turnover columns and then I linked this pivot to that, so that I can get the Turnover years in columns.  Refer the screenshot below

[image]

II) After that I have used ***Calculated field*** instead of ***Calculated item*** and it gives the ***year on year*** and ***CAGR %s*** instead of Sum in the Total column.

By doing this, I got the totals the way I wanted.

Best Regards
VBA Learner